# How to use multipleline in uilabel and automatically extend tableview row height depend upon label height in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I am working on table based iOS application using swift language. I have integrated the UILabel in UITableview cell. I want change the cell heights based on the UILabel height.

Comment: ur usinf Storyboard right

Answer (score 0):

you can set `numberoflines` property to `0` to get multiline label. something like,

```
 yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

You can change label height as per string something like,

```
 //Calculate the expected size based on the font and linebreak mode of your label
 // FLT_MAX here simply means no constraint in height
 CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296, FLT_MAX);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];   

 //adjust the label the the new height.
 CGRect newFrame = yourLabel.frame;
 newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
 yourLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

You can increase height of tableview row by implementing delegate method,

`heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Hope this will help :)

Comment: how to extend tableview automatically depend upon label size in swift 2.0 only not objective-c.please sent me to soon...

Answer (score 0):

First set UILabel line into 0 in Storyboard.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

// need to calculte height of label text
 NSString *comment = [[self.objects objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"Testo"];
    CGFloat whidt =  260;
    UIFont *FONT = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    NSAttributedString *attributedText =[[NSAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:comment  attributes:@  { NSFontAttributeName: FONT }];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){whidt, MAXFLOAT}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    CGSize size = rect.size;
    return size.height +130;
}
```

whidt is label width .